# How do I create a button in javascript that appears next to output? I am including more specification inside

Tags: javascript

In my html file I have a div tag to add output from an external Javascript file which looks like this.

```
<div id="section" class="format" align="left"></div>
```

The output is passed to the div with this code.

```
document.getElementById("section").innerHTML = output;
```

Now, the next piece of code is output that is passed to the code previous to this to be displayed on the webpage. What I want is to add a button that is displayed, on the right, next to the location output in the html file and the code looks like this.

```
output+="Location: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("location")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Well Depth: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("welldepth")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Perf Depth: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("perfdepth")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Perf Zone: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("perfzone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Stroke: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("stroke")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ";
output+="<br>";
output+="Stroke/min: ";
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("strokepermin")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I've tried many different solutions on google and the most notable example is as follows.

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
alert("did something");
});
```

I think it's close but I want the button next to the location output and not after the output as shown in this image.

The thing is though the output is based on a search and the code assigning output to this line,

```
document.getElementById("section").innerHTML = output;
```

is in a loop because multiple results can come from the search.

[Output shown here](https://gyazo.com/f7b20ef1c0a41752393af8a2cdfb6cf9)

I am not sure how I would make a button next to the location output.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply append the markup for the button when assigning each part of markup to *output*?

Comment: Can you add a button to the output variable? @RobG

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: I added this to the part of the function that passes output and it overrides everything

var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                          // Append the text to <p>
    document.getElementById("buttonID").appendChild(btn);

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. Since you are assigning the value of *output* to the *innerHTML* property of a div, you could just include the markup for a button in the value, e.g.

```
output+=x[i].getElementsByTagName("location")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        " <button>Do something</button>";
```

But this seems to be tabular data, so perhaps better to create a table using a helper function that takes the title and text for each row then appends a button, e.g.

```js
function fillTable(id, data) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!table) return;
  var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    tbody.appendChild(makeRow(key, data[key]));
  });
}

function makeRow(title, text) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var titleCell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
  titleCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  var textCell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  textCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  var buttonCell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
  var button = buttonCell.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Do Something'));
  button.onclick = function() {
    console.log('Did something');
  };
  return row;
}

var data = {
  'Location': 'loc0',
  'Well Depth': '23 m'
};

window.onload = function() {
  fillTable('results', data);
};
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
th, td {
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table id="results"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

If you have many sets of data, you might want to run the headers across the top.

Comment: Hello RobG, adding the code "<button> Do something </button>"
works great, how would you add an event to the button if you implement it in this way? Thank you very much Rob @RobG